# TypeError: $ is not a function - toastr.js- AMD and SystemJS

Tags: jquery, aurelia, systemjs, amd

I am getting the following error.

```
toastr.js:60 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $ is not a function
    at getContainer (toastr.js:60)
    at notify (toastr.js:215)
    at r.error (toastr.js:49)
```

**However JQuery has been loaded so I don't understand what is going on.**

### Update

I am starting to understand what is happening.

I edited the following file locally in my folder: `project/jspm_packages\npm\toastr@2.1.2\toastr.js`

Specifically @ around line 470: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/1ef00d723691b563b610077a08539391386826b3/toastr.js#L470

I commented the old code and added the following:

```
}(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define : function (deps, factory) {

    /*if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { //Node
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        window.toastr = factory(window.jQuery);
    }*/

    window.toastr = factory(window.jQuery);
    module.exports = factory(window.jQuery);

}));
```

I have the feeling that the `require('jquery')` command was causing a get request for a file located at `dist/jquery.js`

However, this file did not exist so a colleague created an empty file. 
This fixed the other errors, but it seems that toastr is affected.
I'm not a JS expert but it seems like the `require` function might be creating a local scoped version of jquery (based on the `dist/js` file) and then passing this reference to the constructor/factory of toastr.

### Problem

My problem is that require in toastr is looking for a jquery file in dist that doesn't exist. Is there a way to create a wrapper file that returns the existing JQuery in the expected format?

**I think the wrapper needs to be in AMD format ...**

### package.json contents

```
  {
      "name": "mbak-ui",
      "version": "0.5.0",
      "description": "mbak",
      "keywords": [
        "mbak"       
      ],
      "main": "dist/main.js",
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://MYREPO"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "gulp test",
        "e2e": "gulp serve webdriver-standalone e2e"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "aurelia-bundler": "^0.4.0",
        "aurelia-protractor-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "aurelia-tools": "^1.0.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
        "babel-eslint": "^7.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^2.0.3",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.17.5",
        "conventional-changelog": "1.1.0",
        "del": "^2.2.2",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
        "gulp-bump": "^2.5.0",
        "gulp-changed": "^1.3.2",
        "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1",
        "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-protractor": "3.0.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
        "karma": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-jspm": "2.2.0",
        "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
        "object.assign": "^4.0.4",
        "protractor": "^4.0.10",
        "proxy-middleware": "^0.15.0",
        "require-dir": "^0.3.2",
        "requireg": "^0.1.7",
        "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
        "vinyl-paths": "^2.1.0",
        "yargs": "^6.3.0"
      },
      "jspm": {
        "dependencies": {
          "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@^1.2.1",
          "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-dialog": "npm:aurelia-dialog@^1.0.0-rc.1.0.3",
          "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@^1.0.7",
          "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-testing": "npm:aurelia-testing@^1.0.0-beta.2.0.1",
          "aurelia-validation": "npm:aurelia-validation@^1.0.0",
          "aurelia-view-manager": "npm:aurelia-view-manager@^0.1.0",
          "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@^0.1.35",
          "fetch": "github:github/fetch@^2.0.3",
          "i18next-xhr-backend": "npm:i18next-xhr-backend@^1.4.2",
          "moment": "npm:moment@^2.18.1",
          "select2": "github:select2/select2@^4.0.3",
          "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.11",
          "zui": "MBAKnet:mbak@alpha"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
          "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
          "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
        },
        "overrides": {
          "github:select2/select2@4.0.3": {
            "shim": {
              "select2": [
                "jquery"
              ]
            },
            "dependencies": {
              "jquery": "jspm:jquery@*"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {}
    }
```

### config.js contents

https://gist.github.com/menelaosbgr/94d64c03fd8f010688fb9424b63f36c5

### Solution

I found the answer and posted it. I simply had to install jquery as jquery (into the project):

```
jspm install jquery=jquery
```

Comment: Where has it been loaded? Is it running in noConflict mode? Minimum code to replicate the error?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @Rohit.007 the project is huge. I see though that in the global context $ is JQuery and is working normally. However, in toastr ... it's broken.

Comment: @Rohit.007  @BenM  @Santiago Trejo > I have updated the description. My problem is that `require` in toastr is looking for a jquery file in dist that doesn't exist. Is there a way to create a wrapper file that returns the existing JQuery in the expected format?

Comment: `was causing a get request for a file located at dist/jquery.js`. Did you define in requireJS the jQuery Path? http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: @Sysix we are actually using SystemJS (with JSPM) which I think supports AMD in some way. I noticed the entry ` "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.4",``within a config.js file. I will add config.js and package.json . @Rohit.007 @BenM @Santiago Trejo > I have added package.json and config.json .

Comment: I guess you need to try an NPM install for jquery module.

Comment: @Rohit.007 plus 1, thanks!  I needed to do `jspm install` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that toastr is using the following command, that is expecting a module to be installed.

```
     `module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));`
```

it turns out all I needed was to run:

`jspm install jquery=jquery`

**Reference:**

https://www.sitepoint.com/modular-javascript-systemjs-jspm/